# replacing a column in DataFrame using regex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 4 columns, col4 is a string including texts and digits:

```
 Col1           Col2              Col3           Col4
Syslog        2016,09,17           1    PD380_003 %LINK-3-UPDOWN
Syslog        2016,09,17           1    NM380_005 %BGP-5-NBR_RESET
Syslog        2016,09,14           1    NM380_005 %BGP-5-NBR_RESET
Syslog        2016,09,08           1    DO NOT TICKET LO380_004 %SYS-5-CONFIG_I Config
```

i need to keep a substring of that column and delete anything else, so I used regex and i made a pattern but when i run the following query the result is not what i want, it replace everything with the pattern itself:

```
data.replace({'Col4':{'.*':'([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})'}},regex=True)
```

desired result is:

```
 Col1           Col2              Col3           Col4
Syslog        2016,09,17           1           PD380_003
Syslog        2016,09,17           1           NM380_005
Syslog        2016,09,14           1           LO380_004
Syslog        2016,09,08           1           LO380_004
```

but the result i get is like:

```
 Col1           Col2              Col3           Col4
Syslog        2016,09,17           1    ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})
Syslog        2016,09,17           1    ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})
Syslog        2016,09,14           1    ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})
Syslog        2016,09,08           1    ([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your `data` DF __before__ replacing?

Comment: yes please check it out again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have the wrong regex's in the wrong positions. The `to_replace` argument to [.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas-dataframe-replace) needs to match what to replace and what to delete. So you need a `^.*` in front of and a `.*$` behind your regex in this case since you want to trim the string outside the match:

```
^.*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}).*$
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/X6cypX/3)

Second, the `replace` argument, if a regex, needs to be a capturing group or fixed string. In this case `\1` will do.

Last, the Series form of `.replace` has a littler simpler syntax (at least for me) to understand.

So given:

```
>>> df
     Col1        Col2  Col3                                            Col4
0  SysLog  2016,09,17     1                        PD380_003 %LINK-3-UPDOWN
1  SysLog  2016,09,17     1                      NM380_005 %BGP-5-NBR_RESET
2  SysLog  2016,09,17     1                      NM380_005 %BGP-5-NBR_RESET
3  SysLog  2016,09,17     1  DO NOT TICKET LO380_004 %SYS-5-CONFIG_I Config
```

You can do:

```
>>> df['Col4'].replace(to_replace='^.*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}).*$', value=r'\1', regex=True) 
0    PD380_003
1    NM380_005
2    NM380_005
3    LO380_004
Name: Col4, dtype: object
```

You can also use a positional argument version if easier:

```
df['Col4'].replace('^.*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}).*$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

but you need to have `regex=True` since the replacement string is to be interpreted as a regex -- not just a static string.

Finally, assign directly into the original:

```
>>> df['Col4']=df['Col4'].replace('^.*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}).*$', r'\1', regex=True)
>>> df
     Col1        Col2  Col3       Col4
0  SysLog  2016,09,17     1  PD380_003
1  SysLog  2016,09,17     1  NM380_005
2  SysLog  2016,09,17     1  NM380_005
3  SysLog  2016,09,17     1  LO380_004
```

Comment: thanks for explaining i'm new to Panda this kid of explanation helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
data.Col4 = data.Col4.str.extract('([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})', expand=False)

print (data)
     Col1        Col2  Col3       Col4
0  Syslog  2016,09,17     1  PD380_003
1  Syslog  2016,09,17     1  NM380_005
2  Syslog  2016,09,14     1  NM380_005
3  Syslog  2016,09,08     1  LO380_004
```

Comment: yes it works but i'm just wondering why replace can't read the regex?

Comment: Hmm, I check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and it can works.

Comment: But I think it is bug.

Answer (score 1):

You were using RegEx in a wrong way.

`{'Col4':{'.*':'([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})'}}` - means replace a whatever string in the `Col4` column with `'([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3})'`

Try this:

```
In [87]: df.replace({'Col4':{r'.*?([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}_[0-9]{3}).*':r'\1'}}, regex=True)
Out[87]:
     Col1        Col2  Col3       Col4
0  Syslog  2016,09,17     1  PD380_003
1  Syslog  2016,09,17     1  NM380_005
2  Syslog  2016,09,14     1  NM380_005
3  Syslog  2016,09,08     1  LO380_004
```