# replace a word by another one if contains some specific characters in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to replace words in a Pandas dataframe if they contain some characters.

```
pd.Series(['first mashmalowss ', 'second', 'third row', 'fourth powwww'])
```

I want to replace words that contain 'ow' by the word 'value'. Expected output:

```
pd.Series(['first value ', 'second', 'third value', 'fourth value'])
```

Indeed, values of 1, 3 and 4rth row have a word with the caracters 'ow'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacing a column in DataFrame using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965414/replacing-a-column-in-dataframe-using-regex)

Comment: No because in this question, they are replacing the whole row, and not only the matching words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series `replace` should work

```
s = pd.Series(['first mashmalowss ', 'second', 'third row', 'fourth powwww'])

s1 = s.replace(r'\w*ow\w*', 'value', regex=True)
print(s1)

Out[34]:
0    first value
1          second
2     third value
3    fourth value
dtype: object
```

Comment: perfect !! the optimal one

Answer (score 2):

Use the apply method and a helper function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(['first mashmalowss ', 'second', 'third row', 'fourth powwww']).T,
                  columns=['heading'])

def replace(string: str) -> str:
    if 'ow' in string:
        rv = ''
        for word in string.split():
            rv += ' value' if 'ow' in word else ' ' + word
        return rv.strip()
    else:
        return string

print (df)
print(df['heading'].apply(replace))
```

The function `replace` takes any element of your series and cleans it to your specifications. The `df['heading'].apply(replace)` line applies this function to every value in your series.

Comment: good idea ! Hope it will be useable for large dataframes of more than 1 million rows]